# How do I install IIS7 using C# (or VB)?

Tags: c#, iis-7

I'm trying to install IIS7+ programmically. If I run it directly in the cmd prompt, it runs fine.

```
start /w pkgmgr /l:log.etw /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ASP;IIS-CGI;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;IIS-URLAuthorization;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-ManagementService;IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;IIS-WMICompatibility;IIS-LegacyScripts;IIS-LegacySnapIn;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI
```

Because of the "start" part at the beginning, I'm a little confused on how to run it ServiceProcess.Process class. I can run any other exe that I've needed but pkgmgr.exe doesn't see to play nice.

```
Using proc As New Process()
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\windows\system32\pkgmgr.exe"
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/l:log.etw /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ASP;IIS-CGI;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;IIS-URLAuthorization;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-ManagementService;IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;IIS-WMICompatibility;IIS-LegacyScripts;IIS-LegacySnapIn;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI"
    proc.Start()
    proc.WaitForExit()
End Using
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to play nice"?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Why are you trying to install this from your application?  Normally your apps will not have the correct permissions to do this and it isn't recommended to do this from a security perspective.

Comment: @Geek It's enterprise software that is usually installed on a brand new dedicated server and many of our customers complain about having to do the tedious configurations for our installations.

Comment: @Ek0nomik - it's doesn't nothing and no errors but I'm not doing anything other than what is in the code that I shared in a simple winform app on a button click event run as administrator.

Comment: We have to do the same thing with our packages.  There are always manual steps required to set it up.  For one - with IIS you should never just turn it on and leave it alone.  There are security protocols, configurations, etc that should be considered when enabling the feature - and by installing it yourself - you leave your clients open to potential issues in their environment.  It's best to let them do the setup up front for the "dependencies" your software has.

Answer (score 1):

I found this trustworthy link [Using Unattended Setup to Install IIS 7.0](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/using-unattended-setup-to-install-iis)

STEP 1: PKGMGR.EXE OVERVIEW

Windows Optional features in Vista/Windows Server 2008 is installed using a new command tool called Pkgmgr. The command line syntax using pkgmgr.exe is:

```
Start /w pkgmgr.exe /iu:update1;update2…
```

**Pkgmgr.exe Commands**

/iu:{update name}; 
This specifies updates to install by update name and takes a semicolon separated name of updates to install.

/uu:{update name}; 
This specifies the updates to uninstall and takes a semicolon separated list of selectable updates to be uninstalled from the system. At least one update name must be specified

/n:{unattend XML} 
This specifies file name of the unattend XML file.

Please see the MSDN article for further details about the XML file.

---

eg:

*To install only the IIS 7.0 default features, copy the following unattend.xml text into notepad.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend"  
    xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">
<servicing> 
   <!-- Install a selectable update in a package that is in the Windows Foundation namespace --> 
   <package action="configure"> 
      <ssemblyIdentity 
         name="Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package"
         version="6.0.5308.6"
         language="neutral"
         processorArchitecture="x86"
         publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
         versionScope="nonSxS"
      />
    <selection name="IIS-WebServerRole" state="true"/> 
    <selection name="WAS-WindowsActivationService" state="true"/> 
    <selection name="WAS-ProcessModel" state="true"/> 
    <selection name="WAS-NetFxEnvironment" state="true"/> 
    <selection name="WAS-ConfigurationAPI" state="true"/> 
  </package> 
</servicing> 
</unattend>
```

Comment: Yeah, I referenced this as well but doesn't seem to work from C# app which you don't reference in your answer.  As I mentioned in my post, I can run this code fine from cmd prompt.  It's running it from c# that is the issue.

Comment: Are you running the C# app as an administrator?  If you are debugging - Visual Studio must be run in admin mode.

Comment: Yes, visual studio and the app is run as administrator.

Comment: @RichC follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079030/better-way-to-install-iis7-programmatically