# How to enable/disable Windows Features programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com

I want to turn on/off windows features programmatically.Manually it can be done via control panel->Programs and features->Turn windows feature on or off.

Is there any windows api to do so? or any com interface to mange this?

Comment: Unlikely that there is an API for this. Group policy is more likely. This seems like a sysadmin question. Which feature do you want to enable/disable? And why do you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: I want to enable IIS feature. Requirement is Enable IIS, Check IIS version. I have some applications which require such settings. Hence I want to enable/disable IIS feature programmatically.

Comment: You should ask that specific question then. You don't care about being able to enable/disable a variety of features. All you care about is IIS. Answers will likely be very IIS specific. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079030/better-way-to-install-iis7-programmatically

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [`DismEnableFeature`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh824737.aspx) which is part of [Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh824790.aspx).

Comment: For some reason that does not work in full trust Desktop Bridge apps with 0x80040154 error in `OpenSession`. I ended up calling `DISM.exe` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a powershell script and intall-windowsfeature cmdlet :

`Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server`

[technet link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205467.aspx)