# Enable IIS Roles and Features Programmatically

Tags: c#, iis, dism

I am trying to enable IIS features through c# console application. It is working fine in windows 7 and windows 8.1 machines. but when I run the same code on windows server 2008 R2 and windows server 2012 R2 it is not working. What am I missing in this code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace EnableIISComponents
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SetupIIS();
                Console.WriteLine("Done. Press any key to close.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred:" + ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    static string SetupIIS()
    {
        // In command prompt run this command to see all the features names which are equivalent to UI features.
        // c:\>dism /online /get-features /format:table 
        var featureNames = new List<string> 
                {
                    "IIS-ApplicationDevelopment",                        
                    "IIS-ISAPIExtensions",
                    "IIS-ISAPIFilter",
                    "IIS-CommonHttpFeatures",
                    "IIS-DefaultDocument",
                    "IIS-HttpErrors",
                    "IIS-StaticContent",
                    "IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics",
                    "IIS-HttpLogging",
                    "IIS-HttpTracing",
                    "IIS-WebServer",
                    "IIS-WebServerRole",
                    "IIS-ManagementConsole",
                };

        Console.WriteLine("Checking the Operating System...\n");

        ManagementObjectSearcher obj = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem");
        try
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject wmi in obj.Get())
            {
                string Name = wmi.GetPropertyValue("Caption").ToString();

                // Remove all non-alphanumeric characters so that only letters, numbers, and spaces are left.
                // Imp. for 32 bit window server 2008
                Name = Regex.Replace(Name.ToString(), "[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");

                if (Name.Contains("Server 2012 R2") || Name.Contains("Windows 81"))
                {
                    featureNames.Add("IIS-ASPNET45");
                    featureNames.Add("IIS-NetFxExtensibility45");
                }
                else if (Name.Contains("Server 2008 R2") || Name.Contains("Windows 7"))
                {
                    featureNames.Add("IIS-ASPNET");
                    featureNames.Add("IIS-NetFxExtensibility");
                }
                else
                {
                    featureNames.Clear();
                }

                string Version = (string)wmi["Version"];
                string Architecture = (string)wmi["OSArchitecture"];

                Console.WriteLine("Operating System details:");
                Console.WriteLine("OS Name: " + Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Version: " + Version);
                Console.WriteLine("Architecture: " + Architecture + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred:" + ex.Message);
        }

        return Run(
            "dism",
            string.Format(
                "/NoRestart /Online /Enable-Feature {0}",
                string.Join(
                    " ",
                    featureNames.Select(name => string.Format("/FeatureName:{0}", name)))));
    }

    static string Run(string fileName, string arguments)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enabling IIS features...");
        Console.WriteLine(arguments);

        using (var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            Arguments = arguments,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
        }))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
            return process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Instead of running this program on server machine If I run the dism command with same feaureNames through command prompt, the IIS features are getting enabled. Why not it is working with the program?

I am running my program as administrator by right clicking and selecting "run as administrator".

I have created this sample taking help from this link. 
[Better way to install IIS7 programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079030/better-way-to-install-iis7-programmatically)

Comment: I compiled your code and it works just fine on a fresh Server 2012 R2. Check your dism logs `C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log` for the server where it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found the cause.
In project properties target platform is "Any CPU"
but "Prefer 32-bit" option was checked. This causing the problem.
In server 2012 R2 my application trying to use 32bit version of DISM. That is causing the problem.

Once I unchecked that option. It is working fine.