# Programmatically Installing IIS Windows Server 2016 using C# or WixToolset

Tags: c#, iis-7, windows-server-2016

Since its so new I haven't been able to find much documentation on the subhject. I need to programmatically install IIS on windows server 2016. Could anyone help me off the struggle bus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out two best links for you,

https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-install-iis-in-windows-server-2016/

[Better way to install IIS7 programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079030/better-way-to-install-iis7-programmatically)

Their they have explained clearly and hope that will be surely helpful for you.kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks
thanks
karthik

Comment: The root users link worked for me. Thank you ! I actually had already tried it before I posted this but didn't think that it worked because after I made the call I couldn't find the IIS manager when i searched in the lil search bar of windows in the bottom left nor could i find the IIS manager in programs and features  sometimes the windows indexer doesn't work right on Winserver. So i made the PowerShell call but then when i search programs for IIS manager i couldn't find it so i thought it didn't work but i had to drill down into Windows Administrative tools and I found it there.